# Copy data between Dropbox and OneDrive, small local drive

Tags: synchronization, dropbox, onedrive

I am aware that this may not be the best community to ask this question - if this is the case, please point me to the right direction.

I have some 300GB data stored in Dropbox cloud (various files, usually around 1-50 MB in size). I need to copy the data onto my OneDrive.

My local drive is only 128GB, 90GB available.

How to copy my Dropbox files across to OneDrive? I would like to avoid attaching external drives to the local machine. Also, I'd like this process to be as cost-effective as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there can be some naming issues and such if you copy directly.

But one simple and direct approach.

1. Download 70-90GB from Dropbox
2. Upload to OneDrive
3. If notDone Go To 1.

Comment: This is the most obvious, yes. However, because of the nature of the cloud storage, I need local folders (partially synchronized) for both Dropbox and Onedrive, so I can't do more than 40GB in one cycle. I was hoping to find some cloud - to - cloud solution that wouldn't require me to download / upload the stuff through my (relatively slow) Internet connection.

Comment: The only ones I see that automate the task are ridiculously high priced for such a short job (looking again first one is $199). Not sure how OneDrive works, so no idea how one would download to there (ie from a source like Dropbox) instead of uploading from local storage. I just know you can run into naming issues (if filenames contain non-standard letters) when copying from Dropbox to OneDrive.

Comment: I found a solution, finally. I discovered that my NAS box has both Dropbox and OneDrive clients built-in so now it is really about juggling files on the NAS box and not touching my local drive at all.